# Maven equivalent to Gradle's flatDir

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle flatDir and it's working pretty great for me, but I also work on a Maven project in which I want the same functionalities. Is there any Maven equivalent to the following code?

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'D:/path/to/local/directory'
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is a flatDir? Which functionality do you need?

Comment: I vaguely remember a defect in gradle where `flatDir` will not be supported anymore?